# Gulp BootstrapCSS source maps

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm trying to generate the following `CSS Source Map` files, through `gulp.js` for the `BootstrapCSS` library.

My gulp task is as folows:

bower = require 'main-bower-files' 
sourcemaps = require 'gulp-sourcemaps' 
cssmin = require 'gulp-minify-css'
gulpFilter = require 'gulp-filter'

```
gulp.task 'compileVendorLibraries', ->
    cssFilter = gulpFilter(['**/*.css'])
    gulp.src bower()
    .pipe cssFilter
    .pipe gulp.dest(dist.css + 'css')
    .pipe sourcemaps.init()
    .pipe rename({suffix: ".min"})
    .pipe cssmin()
    .pipe sourcemaps.write()
    .pipe cssFilter.restore()
```

And in `index.html` I have:

```
<link href="app/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

However, I dont get the "original" `bootstrap.css` file in Chrome (source maps are activated)

Whereas when I do it for my custom `.less` files as follows, I get the my original "styles.less" file:

```
gulp.src sources.less
    .pipe sourcemaps.init()
    .pipe less()
    .on 'error', swallowError
    .pipe cssmin()
    .pipe sourcemaps.write()
    .pipe gulp.dest dist.css + 'css'
```

Comment: Is your gulp task complete? I'm missing the part where you store bootstrap.min.css. Also, I'm wondering if you want to create a sourcemap out of the newly saved bootstrap.css. If so, that won't work as you would have to change your source after the save.

Comment: And another one: Where does your Chrome think the sourcemap is? $stdin?